# Reusable Action in Ext JS MVC

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

I have a Grid Panel with a toolbar and an context menu.
The toolbar has a edit button and the context menu has a edit menu item. 
Both shares the same properties (text, icon and handler)

Ext has something called Action which makes it possible to share functionality etc. between components, but til now I have had no success getting it to work in the MVC architecture
(I am using the new MVC architecture in 4.0)

My Action class looks like this:

```
Ext.define( 'App.action.EditAction', {
    extend: 'Ext.Action',
    text: 'Edit',
    handler: function()
    {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Click', 'You did something.');
    },
    iconCls: 'icon-edit-user' ,
});
```

And in my context menu

```
requires: ['App.action.EditAction'],
initComponent: function()
{
    var editUser = new App.action.EditAction();

    this.items = [
        editUser,
        {
            // More menuitems
        }
        ...
     ];

     this.callParent(arguments);
```

When running the code I get "config is undefined" in the console.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

t

Answer (score 2):

Passing an empty config to your constructor will avoid the error, but have unwanted consequences later because, unfortunately, the base class (`Ext.Action`) relies on `this.initialConfig` later on.  For example, if you called `editUser.getText()` it would return `undefined` instead of the expected `'Edit'`.

Another approach is to override your constructor to allow a no-arg invocation and apply your overridden configuration:

```
Ext.define( 'App.action.EditAction', {
    extend: 'Ext.Action',
    text: 'Edit',
    constructor: function(config) 
    {
        config = Ext.applyIf(config || {}, this);
        this.callParent([config]);
    },
    handler: function()
    {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Click', 'You did something.');
    },
    iconCls: 'icon-edit-user' ,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Ext.Action constructor

```
constructor : function(config){
    this.initialConfig = config;
    this.itemId = config.itemId = (config.itemId || config.id || Ext.id());
    this.items = [];
}
```

You must supply config not to get `config is undefined` exception in the second line (precisely in `config.itemId` part).

Updating your code as `var editUser = new App.action.EditAction({});` should help(passing new empty object as config).
Surely, you could add some properties to the config object too.