# ExtJS cannot override methods statics

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I wanted to extend `Ext.Action` class due to add my own methods, but I've encouraged problem `Cannot override method statics on Core.app.Action instance`.

I know that is a problem connected to overriding constructor. But don't know how to solve it other way.

Here is code of my component

```
Ext.define('Core.app.Action', {
    extend: 'Ext.Action',
    iconCls: 'icon-add',
    currentData: undefined,

    constructor: function(config){
        config = Ext.applyIf(config || {}, this);
        this.callParent([config])
    },

    handler: function (widget, event) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Name:", this.currentData.data.company)
    },

    getActionId: function () {
        return this.actionId
    },

    setCurrentData: function (data) {
        this.currentData = data
        this.disable()
        if (data.data.actions) {
            this.currentData.data.actions.forEach(action => {
                if (action === this.actionId) this.enable()
            })
        }
    }

})
```

And there is a way how I create instance of mentioned class

```
Ext.create('Core.app.Action', {
    actionId: 'D',
    text: "Action D",
})
```

ExtJS is not throwing errors when I remove constructor from my class, but I can't also use methods such as handler or setCurrentData.

I've also tried overriding the component, but failed.

Answers in solution below weren't helpful in this case. 
[Reusable Action in Ext JS MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677691/reusable-action-in-ext-js-mvc)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce using the provided code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2emk).

Comment: @Alexander obviously you can't beacouse something is wrong with the way I've tried implement it, but so far I don't know where is the mistake.